# Confusion regarding a 12V DC motor's RPM

Tags: motor, dc, 12v, gear

I have a 550 DC motor of 12V, 45W and 10K RPM installed on a wheel, which is not causing the wheel to turn fast enough when the motor is connected to a 12V battery.
I replaced the motor with an older DC motor which I had, having the same specs of the replacement, however with 9K RPM (I thought it would be slower).
Sarcastically it generated more speed to the wheel than the 10K RPM one.
Some electrician told me to ignore the labeling on the DC motors outside since they are not accurate.
I wasted plenty of time trying to fix the issue by following the book higher RPM means higher speed. I first thought that the gear train inside the gearbox was the issue, but I used the same gearbox for the older 9K RPM motor and still it gave higher speed.
I am willing to buy additional DC motor but I need to generate even higher speed, I am confused to whether I should buy a higher or lower RPM DC motor for this purpose.

The following are the full specs of the project:
**MOTOR1**
Power:20-45W
Voltage:12 V 
RPM:10,000

**MOTOR2**
Power:20-45W
Voltage:12 V 
RPM:9,000

each motor was individually attached to gear train having the following teeth:

Motor1 turns a 10 teeth pinion, which turns a 52 teeth cylinder C1, attached to C1 is a little cylinder C1' having 10 teeth again, C1' turns a cylinder, C2, having 48 teeth, attached to C2 is C2' having 9 teeth, C2' turns a the last cylinder C3 having 38 teeth, connected to a wheel. After doing some calculations, the final output for the gear train would be **100RPM**

Motor2, before replacement, had the following installations:

Motor2 turns an 11 teeth pinion, which turns a 56 teeth cylinder C1, attached to C1 is an 11 teeth cylinder C1', turning a 45 teeth cylinder C2, C2 is attached to C2' 11 teeth cylinder, C2' is turning a 42 teeth cylinder C3, C3 is finally attached to the wheel. The final output of motor2 in the above gear train would be **112RPM**

Comment: What is a "550 DC motor"? 550 watt? "*... higher RPM means higher speed.*" That's true because RPM is a speed measurement. Please edit your question add links to the datasheets for the two motors. The datasheet should give details on speed versus load. "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [provide higher speed to a power wheel](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/456064/provide-higher-speed-to-a-power-wheel)

Comment: No 550 is the size of the motor, the DC motor is of 45W , 12V, i will add photos similar to the combinations I have.

Comment: RPM is Revolutions Per Minute => rotational speed. More means more. Whether a datasheet for any given motor is accurate is another matter. Unfortunately, some manufacturers lie about what their product does. This tends to happen more at the cheaper end of the market, as people who buy on price alone tend to be more gullible, and tend not to have the right equipment to verify wild claims.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I was actually astonished when the electrician told me to ignore the labeling on the DC motor, I mean I have been working on the project for a week off and on taking, connecting wires adding batteries. That's the only explanation "manufacturers lie about products"

Comment: Run each motor by itself (not in the gearbox) connected to a high current power source (eg. 12V car battery). Which one _sounds_ like it is running faster? If you have a multimeter, measure the current (on 10A or 20A range). Which one draws more?

Comment: The 9K has a higher sound it is obvious, the 10K motor is rather silent compared to the screaming 9K, I'm not sure about the current though

Comment: Data sheets please. Pictures are no substitute on this occasion.

Comment: What is the actual *mechanical wattage* of your gearbox-plus-wheel? Note that 10,000 RPM is roughly 5X faster than common AC industrial motors (1800RPM wo/load.) 10KRPM, that's really roaring: more like a wood-router! Why? At those high speeds, the bearings and the air-pumping effects may easily consume most of the motor's 45watt mechanical output, and drag down the RPM far below the rating for unloaded RPM. In other words, what is your application? In detail? Why not just use a common 1000RPM motor? Why is 10X higher RPM even being considered? And why use a gearbox?

Comment: The gearbox is like a group of cylinders turning each other, gear train, the gearbox isnthen attached to a wheel, causing it to turn at a specific speed, the gearbox works as a resistor to the spinning of the motor, it doesnt let the whole 10k rpm hit the wheel, thebwattage of the motor is 45W, however i discovered that the labeling on the motor ia false since when compared to my second 9k rpm motor, it appeared to be a turtle speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC motor RPM is highly dependent on load. Motors sold for industrial usually have specifications that provide RPM at rated load. Motors sold for hobby use often state the no-load RPM. Sellers of motors for hobby use often don't pay much attention to accuracy, clarity and completeness of specifications. I suspect that the problem is not so much that manufacturer's lie but that some manufacturers sell junk.

A gear that reduces the motor speed from 10,000 RPM to 100 RPM represents a significant percentage of the motor's load. Differences an the quality and age of the gears may have a significant impact on the output speed of a 45 watt motor.

Comment: Thanks for the input, the majority of the colleagues here who are working on similar projects are trying to manipulate the voltage of the input to control/add speed to the wheel, I will try to do that differently by manipulating the cylinders inside the gear and/or motor. Thank you all for the comments

Comment: If you want to have a specific speed with changing load, temperature, wear of components etc., an electronic speed controller is essential.

Comment: ok, I have to check it out